# Как вставить перед числом такое же число

Tags: delphi-7

Как вставить перед числом такое же число, т.е если ввели 1 то будет 11, есть код но он немного не так работает как надо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про замену по регулярному выражению.
Но, если очень уж хочется перебором символов строки, то нужно так:

- создать пустую строковую переменную `res := ''` для результата
- и пустую строковую переменную `tmp := ''` для временной строки из цифр
- булеву переменную для маркера `label := false`

Далее проходим по символам:

- если символ не 0-9, и `label := false`, записываем его в `res`
- если символ 0-9 и `label := false`, ставим `label := true`, а символ записываем в `tmp`
- если символ 0-9 или ./, и `label := true`, символ записываем в `tmp`
- если символ 0-9 и не ./, (или конец строки, или ./, но в `tmp` уже есть одна ./,) и `label := true`, то в `res` пишем `tmp` + `tmp`, `tmp` очищаем, ставим `label := false` и,  если не конец строки, то текущий символ записываем в `res`

Это для положительных конечных десятичных дробей. для натуральных немного проще, но все равно малость запутанно.
Регулярки эффективнее.

хотя, если в поле ввода будут вводиться только цифры, то можно тупо взять содержимое это поля и 2 раза вставить в поле вывода результата.

Comment: Очень усложненное решение .. откуда-то взялись правила по `.` и `,`, дроби, регулярки, брр-р!

Answer (score 0):

Гораздо проще, просто надо развернуть цикл:

```
s := '1 3 2 0';

for I := Length(s) downto 1 do
  if s[I] in ['0'..'9'] then
    Insert(s[I], s, I); 

// s = '11 33 22 00'
```

Новый элемент вставится там, где мы уже были и не повлияет на итерацию.